# Content Not Moving Between Classes?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios7

I am writing an app that is transferring data from one class to another. For some reason the text is not being displayed on the other view when it is supposed to.

My code:

.h Master class:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@class SSWSettings;

@interface SSWSelectProgram : UITableViewController

@property (strong, nonatomic) SSWSettings *detailViewController;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *p1;

@end
```

.m master class:

```
#import "SSWSelectProgram.h"

#import "SSWSettings.h"

@interface SSWSelectProgram ()

@end

@implementation SSWSelectProgram

@synthesize p1;

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];


}
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cellChosen = [self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (cellChosen == static1) {

         self.detailViewController.detailItem = p1.text;

         [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:NULL];
}
```

.h detail class

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface SSWSettings : UITableViewController <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (strong, nonatomic) id detailItem;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *detailDescriptionLabel;

@end
```

.m detail class
    #import "SSWSettings.h"
    #import "SSWSelectProgram.h"

```
@interface SSWSettings ()

-(void)configureView;

@end

@implementation SSWSettings
@synthesize detailDescriptionLabel;

- (void)setDetailItem:(id)newDetailItem
{
    if (_detailItem != newDetailItem) {
        _detailItem = newDetailItem;

        // Update the view.
        [self configureView];
    }
}

- (void)configureView
{
    // Update the user interface for the detail item.

    if (self.detailItem) {
        self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = [self.detailItem description];
    }
}
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
     [self configureView];
}
```

Comment: Did you try troubleshooting it?

Comment: Done any debugging? Are the properties all non-nil?

Answer (score -1):

Your object "detailItem" is of type id.

Thus, it does not inherit from NSObject and the

```
[self.detailItem description];
```

call Will not return anything.

Try

```
self.detailDescriptionLabel.text = (NSString*) self.detailItem;
```

A better solution, of course, is to not use the type 'id' and use NSString

Comment: How would I change it to become a NSString because it did not work?

Comment: Make sure it is a NSString *, it should work. If not, please provide some details on the error

Comment: I dont get an error in Xcode, but when I run it in the simulator nothing appears in the label.

Comment: Are you sure there is text in the label p1? Is p1 connected in the interface builder?
There are a couple things that can be happening